# SQL Server : get DATETIME to last 30 minutes

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a small stored procedure (in SQL Server 2012) that calculates the number of minutes since the start of the year (and some other things). Currently it calculates the minutes up to the current time which is `2019-01-02 10:29:28.910` using:

```
SET @startDate = (SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
SET @endDate = GETDATE()

SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @startdate, @endDate)
```

Ideally I would like to change this to the last 30 minute mark so if I ran it now it would display `2019-01-02 10:00:00.000` and if I ran it at `2019-01-02 10:42:28.910` it would return `2019-01-02 10:30:00.000` and so on.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

One Method would be to use the modulus operator to subtract the remainder when divided by 30:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime2(0),
        @EndDate datetime2(0);
SET @StartDate = (SELECT DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0));
SET @EndDate = GETDATE();
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate) - (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartDate, @EndDate) % 30),@StartDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your end date using **DATETIMEFROMPARTS**, you'll just need some basic logic for creating your dat as you prefer.

something like:

```
.......

DECLARE @minute int 
set @minute = --insert your logic here
SET @endDate = DATETIMEFROMPARTS ( @year, @month, @day, @hour, @minute, 0, 0 )
```

Here some [ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)